# How can I animate a Button entity from one place to another in ursina engine?

Tags: python-3.x, animation

I am new to Ursina engine . I want to animate a button entity from one place to another using the animate_z method, but am unable to do so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use animate_position(). animate_z will only change the depth, so you won't see the effect unless you have thing behind or in front, or if it's 3d.